# Unable to add QT version

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using QT for the first time to build a GUI. I'm following this [Tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners).

I followed the steps one by one as shown in the screenshot below.

Select the project

[image]

I selected Other project>>Empty qmake Project.  Next I'm prompted to add the Kits.

Add Kits

[image]

I add the Kits, but in the next Tab "Qt Versions", there are no QT versions.

No QT Version

[image]

I figured i didn't install any QT Versions during the installation process. so I opened up the "Add or remove programs" and found that these are the components I have installed.

Installed components

[image]

Will these suffice to build a Desktop GUI using QT creator or are there any other components I have to install as well?

Comment: Seems like you only installed the qtcreator and no actual version of qt. Can you check wether the following file exists:  'home/Qt5.13.1/5.11.1/MSVC_64/bin/qmake'?

Comment: i have the qmake in this location. 
C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017_64\bin

Comment: What happens if you manually add your qmake file then?

Comment: Andrea's answer below got it working. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for a first try, I suggest using the MinGW compiler, since it is installed by Qt Maintenance Tool.

If you need to use the MSVC compiled Qt like the one selected in your pick, but you need also to install Visual Studio since you need the MSVC Compiler. If you also need to debug an MSVC Qt Application via QtCreator you need to manually configure the CDB, since the one installed with Visual Studio is not detected by Qt Creator.
Those pieces of information are related to MSVC2017 and Visual Studio 2017. If you intend to use MSVC2019 I don't know how QtCreator manages that.

About your situation is strange, you installed the MSVC Qt so they should be detected in QtCreator (tools -> options -> kits -> Qt Versions). I suggest to completely uninstall Qt and restart the process selecting just the MinGW 64-bit, QtCreator and MinGW Compiler 7.

Comment: tbh, i didn't install the MSVC the first time around. But after i encountered the above mentioned problem, i figured i might as well install it, based on this link that i found. 
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html 
I'll wait for a few more replies and then try the complete uninstall/install. In the meantime, i'll try the MinGW Compiler

Comment: But if you installed the MSVC library with the Maintenance Tool, Qt Creator should detect it. With MinGW, all the procedure is smoother!

Comment: it worked. I added the MinGW compiler and it worked. I don't know the significance of MinGW , but it did work. Thank you.